# Where do professional designers go to look for typefaces?

Tags: typography, resource-recommendations, typefaces, font-design

I was reading *The Non-Designer's Design Book* by Robin Williams and was very impressed how on almost every page, Ms. Williams seems to "pull out" some beautiful typeface which I've never heard of. I'm not a design professional, but this got me wondering:

- Where do professional designers find their typefaces? Any books you can buy with nothing but type samples? Certain websites which are commonly used by "the pros"?

Comment: See also the question [Visual typeface search tool](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/15800/visual-typeface-search-tool) for what we (I presume: or at least, I) *would* do to look for typefaces, if such a thing existed and worked well...

Answer (score 29, accepted):

While this is primarily a list of sites, know that browsing a website is not the only way to look for typefaces. Some type foundries still publish specimen catalogs, and some now have mobile apps and Adobe plugins. Many will also have e-mail newsletters to update on new things.

- [MyFonts](http://www.myfonts.com/)
- [FontFont](http://www.fontfont.com/)
- [Typophile](http://typophile.com/)
- [Letterhead Fonts](http://letterheadfonts.com/)
- [Linotype](http://www.linotype.com/)
- [FontShop](http://www.fontshop.com/) – A great collection of fonts including all of the FontFont collection. They have a [plugin](http://www.fontshop.com/plugin/) to help you browse while you work and their now-digital [FontBook](http://www.fontbook.com/) is a really extensive thing.
- [Emigre](http://www.emigre.com/) – One of the pioneers of digital typography, but they've continued to make quality type. You might recognize [Mrs Eaves](http://www.emigre.com/EF.php?fid=109) from the WordPress logo. You can also get their [catalogs](http://www.emigre.com/EmigreCatalog.php) for just a couple of bucks.
- [House Industries](http://www.houseind.com/fonts/) – Prolific, cool, unique. They have some great fonts. They distribute their well-designed [catalogs](https://www.houseind.com/catalog/) for free. They also run a website called [Photo-Lettering](http://www.photolettering.com/) where you can buy typeset headlines at a low flat price if you don't want to pay the full price for a font you'll only use once.
- [Sudtipos](http://sudtipos.com/fonts) – Their stuff is available on MyFonts, but sometimes it's nice to browse straight from the foundry. They tend to make really high-quality, script-y, hand-lettered-looking stuff.
- [Hoefler & Frere Jones](http://www.typography.com/)
- [Chank](http://chank.com/) – Mostly quirky display faces.
- [Process Type](http://processtypefoundry.com/)
- [Font Bros](http://www.fontbros.com/) – Specializing in Retro faces
- [Lost Type Co-Op](http://losttype.com/%20Lost%20Type%20Co-op) – a foundry releasing on a 'pay-what-you-want' pricing model. One of the few places to get a really nice set of curated faces for very little money (free, if you want). The drawback, however, is their stuff tends to be over-used.
- [Adobe](http://www.adobe.com/type/fontfinder/) – one of the grandfathers of the type foundries.
- [Okay Type Foundry](http://okaytype.com)

### Webfonts

- [Webtype](http://webtype.com)
- [Fontsquirrel](http://www.fontsquirrel.com/) – Great free webfont packages with the actual different vector versions. Also has a tool to generate webfonts from your own ttf fonts.
- [Google Fonts](http://www.google.com/webfonts) – Massive selection of CDN hosted fonts that you can also download for desktop use
- [Typekit](https://typekit.com/) – Commercial webfont provider

---

I ***encourage*** others to edit this post and add additional links if something has been missed. But please try and refrain from specific, opinion-based, typeface recommendations. This should be a list of where a user can find typefaces, not what specific fonts you feel are better than others.

---

I don't think there's any typeface "commonly used by professionals." Every designer has their own preferred typefaces. And many designers simply use what's on their system and rarely, if ever, purchase additional fonts unless they are forced to.

Comment: Just FYI, Letterheadfonts has a rocky history. Some info: http://typophile.com/node/30452

Comment: And MyFonts is a great place these days. They sell type from many, many foundries and their newsletter is a great way to see what's new out there.

Comment: @DA01 Sorry, that post at Typophile is completely contrary to my experience. I notice that's a 2007 post. Perhaps they've changed things. I download and install fonts from letterheadfonts.com the same way I do from MyFonts.com. There's absolutely no difference and I've purchased dozens of fonts from both sites.

Comment: I'll just chip in and mention FontShop.com - it has all of the FontFonts plus other stuff.

Comment: @Scott I'm not saying you didn't have a good experience, but there have been several threads over the years pertaining to Letterhead Fonts and their business practices. I merely encourage people to do a bit of research on them. FYI, they do release some of their designer's fonts through MyFonts now, so I'd go that route if given the choice.

Comment: (I should note that I've had no direct experience with LHF good or bad.)

Comment: @Brendan the House Industries link is rather dated. Nothing really new since the mid 1990s. Not that it's bad stuff... just stale. :)

Comment: @Scott - Aw, come on! Love those guys! :P I *think* they've beefed up Neutraface with extra weights relatively recently and the Photo-Lettering initiative is pretty new. Girard happened a couple years ago too I think.

Comment: Possibly :) I just remember 99% of what's there from more than 15 years ago :) Not that old type is bad type. And House does shoot for a "dated" aspect in many fonts. My point was, **check that since once a decade and you've seen all they have to offer**.

Comment: That's fair...at least in terms of typography :)

Comment: @scott house industries has been active for decades. I wouldn't call their stuff stale at all. In fact, they've been release all sorts of items in their PhotoLettering line: http://www.photolettering.com/ I'll add a few more foundries.

Comment: Just saying... everything I see at houseind.com was available in 1996 (or at least 95%). photolettering.com is new to me. But I'm having a bit of difficulty seeing the value in it. Perhaps my browser doesn't support what's so special about it - set a word in a typeface and pay for it. The typefaces are okay, but it hardly seems "custom" to me. I've been through the how-to a dozen times and still don't see a way to "customize" anything other than color.

Comment: ...and I do not mean to give the impression I think the House type is bad. Not at all. They've just been around for a long time and visiting houseind.com often wouldn't really be very beneficial. Get in grab what you like and you're done.

Comment: I'd add fontspring.com, theu have a great selection and good licencing options

Answer (score 7):

Not exactly an answer on "where to go to find fonts", Scott has mentioned the best places to do that, but in my experience it's great to also start from history.

A good book on typography (one of my favorites and excellent if you are new to the subject is [Just my Type](http://www.simongarfield.com/pages/books/just_my_type.htm) by Simon Garfield) can give you a solid foundation on how typefaces have been developing since they were first created / used.

Every font choice has a reason behind it, it tells a story or at transmits something. This is what opened my eyes to the amazing art of typography, so I guess I'm a font-history advocate :)

Answer (score 3):

For good quality fonts you might want to search for Font Foundry on whatever your favorite search engine is and then look at some of the current foundries around. One nice one is [Lost Type Foundry](http://www.losttype.com). Generally a font foundry is going to be much higher quality then a lot of the other sites that just have thousands of fonts from anyone that got their hands on the required software.

Another suggestion is to look up articles on top fonts on sites like [Smashing Magazine](http://www.smashingmagazine.com/tag/free-fonts/) or [Six Revisions](http://sixrevisions.com/graphics-design/25-high-quality-free-fonts-for-professional-designs/).

I'm not familiar with any books that just have fonts but there are font CDs, most notably is [Adobe Fontfolio](http://www.adobe.com/products/fontfolio.html%20%22Adobe%20FontFolio) which I believe is now in version 11.

Answer (score 2):

[Dafont](http://www.dafont.com) is another source for free fonts, but be advised some (most?) are only free for *personal* use, not *commercial* use. Make sure you read the author's notes regarding licensing.

Comment: Professional designers don't go to dafont all that often. I wouldn't exactly call dafont's offerings 'quality' most of the time.

Comment: There are a few diamonds in the rough though!

Comment: define professional....at the very least, dafont offers a cornucopia of reference/inspiration material. [the rest of this comment was edited because it received flags as offensive]

Answer (score 2):

Just adding a few to the ones already posted:

- [T26](http://www.t26.com/fonts)
- [You Work For Them](https://www.youworkforthem.com/fonts)
- [Village Fonts](http://vllg.com/fonts)
- [Font Smith](http://www.fontsmith.com/fonts)
- [Grilli Type](https://www.grillitype.com/typefaces) – made in Switzerland
- [Lineto](https://lineto.com) – made in Switzerland

Answer (score 2):

Go to [Google Fonts](http://google.com/fonts). You can get the font files and they have a wide range of open source fonts. You can choose what font you want based on width, slant, style, script, thickness, and much more.

Answer (score -4):

If you are a business or if you have a legal department; using free fonts is a good way to open your company to a lawsuit since open source basically makes you liable for anyone who ripped it off.

Just go with a professional grade library like fonts.com

I wouldn't take a free computer off the street from someone if my company needed a cheaper way to run

Comment: Do you have any source for this rather huge claim of liability?