# Aware of a font made from uniform straight lines?

Tags: fonts, font-recommendation

I’ve searched for awhile and haven‘t found anything.  What I'm looking for is letters and numbers (specifically *1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, A, E, N, T, R)* that can be “drawn” using a hammer and straight 1/2" chisel.  Here is a rudimentary example:

[image]

The cross hatches where the lines intersect are not important.

I attempted to make myself but all I could manage was the *E.* Even other straight letters like the *N* and *A* were beyond my skills.

I figured it would be out there somewhere, but so far no luck.

Comment: Is a low resolution bitmap facsimile an option? There are plenty of 8x8 "pixel" fonts available.

Comment: See this question, there are many links where you can do your own research. There will be plenty of options: http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/15926/where-do-professional-designers-go-to-look-for-typefaces

Comment: http://www.myfonts.com/fonts/greyscale-type/town/23-lines-black/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did some searching, and here are a few close examples:

Bungee Hairline-
https://fonts.google.com/specimen/Bungee+Hairline

Unica One-
https://fonts.google.com/specimen/Unica+One

Sadly, none of these meet your exact needs, but they could serve as good inspiration.

Comment: Another one is Geostar: https://fonts.google.com/specimen/Geostar

Comment: Thanks for your efforts.  SE keeps bugging me to pick an answer, so I've picked this one (as the only one) even though they didn't meet my needs.  I do appreciate you trying.

Answer (score 2):

This typeface, Homestead, sounds like it could work for you.

http://www.losttype.com/font/?name=homestead

[image: Homestead specimen (via Lost Type]