# Commercial fonts questions

Tags: fonts

Question 1:
I'm looking to design a logo and would need a font to go with it. 
If I find a font that I like, but would have to buy it. 
I don't want to buy as I would like to experiment it first with using Illustrator. 
Is there a website out there that would enable me to download any font to experiment before I buy? If so, what are they?

Question 2:
I'm struggling to understand whether it's legal and safe to use 'free commercial' fonts from Font Squirrel or Da Font for my logo? Their terms and conditions are not clear and please help me out!

Comment: A lot of (subscription base)d resource sites like envato elements have trial licenses that allow you to download the font to try it out before actually using it out in the real world.

Answer (score 2):

Most commercial font [foundries](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/15926) will offer a live preview where you type in your word (eg. company name supposed to appear in the actual logo) and then you can download this as a PNG, which you can then use for mockups while developing the logo and presenting drafts to the client. Many times there will also be a font size selector so you can increase the font size enough to provide a decently sized PNG to work with.

Some foundries, like [Grilli Type](https://www.grillitype.com/free_trials), actually allow you to download reduced demo versions of their fonts with a limited character set (generally only including letters and numbers).

Answer (score 0):

1. Take a Screenshot of the letters you need and retrace them in AI, there is no official test-version of a commercial font.
2. If you use your logo for 'commercial issues' a 'free commercial' licence should cover this. But if you are unsure, ask the font creator!